# What´s the criteria for choose a appropriate in this question?

Tags: calculus, integration

Taking a look at [this page](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-do-integration-by-parts.html),

Why did the editor choose $\ln(x)$ for $u$. It´s because is more simple to differentiate?

Comment: Think in this way:  What would happen if you make $u=\sqrt{x}$? What is the $u'$? Also, isn't that more difficult to integrate $\ln(x)$ instead of $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\ln{x}$ is simple to differentiate and harder to integrate.  (It's not actually that hard, but relatively speaking...)  So in integration by parts, $\ln{x}$ is frequently chosen as the piece that gets differentiated so long as the piece that is integrated (i.e., $dv$) is simple.  In this case, $\sqrt{x}$ is very simple, so the scheme used by the editor is very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at this integral, rather than trying to decide how to make integration by parts fit, I ask myself whether I want to do integration by parts at all.  This technique should be done for a reason.

In this case, the reason is this: differentiating $\ln x$ gives $x$ to a power.  Combined with $x$ to a power that you get by integrating $\sqrt{x}$, the result will still be $x$ to a power, which we know how to integrate.  Hence I know that integration by parts will do something beneficial if done this way.